# Как через кнопки QComboBox добавить текст QTextBrowser и QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qtextedit, qcombobox

Нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопки в `QComboBox` добавлялся текст в `QTextBrowser` и `QLabel`.

```
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

mywindow = QWidget()
mywindow.resize(250, 150)

text_browser = QTextEdit()
text_browser.setHtml('h')
cursor = text_browser.textCursor()
cursor.setPosition(2000)

items = ['1', '2', '3']

combobox = QComboBox()
combobox.addItems(items)


box = QVBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(text_browser)
box.addWidget(combobox)

mywindow.setLayout(box)
mywindow.setWindowTitle('My Window')
mywindow.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Проблема в том, что количество кнопок динамично и на каждую кнопку нужно назначить свою команду добавления текста в `QTextBrowser` и `QLabel` из-за будущей связи с базой данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QComboBox::[**textActivated**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#textActivated)(const QString &text)
>
> Этот сигнал отправляется, когда пользователь выбирает элемент в поле со списком. 
> Текст элемента передается. Обратите внимание, что этот сигнал отправляется, даже если выбор не изменен. 
> Если вам нужно знать, когда выбор действительно изменится, используйте сигнал `currentIndexChanged()` или `currentTextChanged()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        
        self.label = QLabel()

        self.text_browser = QTextEdit()
        self.text_browser.setHtml('Hellow QTextEdit')
        
        items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']
        self.combobox = QComboBox()
        self.combobox.addItems(items)
        self.combobox.textActivated.connect(self.cb_activate)        # !!! +++
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox) 

    def cb_activate(self, text):                                      # !!! +++
        self.label.setText(text)
        self.text_browser.append(text)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyWindow()
    w.resize(500, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('My Window')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]